# How to run several programs one after another asynchronously

Tags: process, async

I want to run several programs one after another and display their output in a single buffer. I can do this by calling `call-process` multiple times:

```
(call-process "cmd1" nil "*out*" t)
(call-process "cmd2" nil "*out*" t)
...
```

The problem is that Emacs freezes until the last `call-process` finishes.

How to execute several programs sequentially (one after another) without freezing Emacs?

Comment: (1) Asynchronously call a single wrapper process which calls, synchronously, all the child processes. (2) Use process sentinels to kick off each process when the preceding process completes.

Comment: I'd like to avoid (1) if possible. Could you please elaborate a bit about process sentinels? Thanks!

Comment: See the manual: `C-h i g (elisp) Sentinels`

Comment: lawlist was playing with this kind of thing a while ago, so you can see one approach to the same problem at http://stackoverflow.com/q/23237869

Comment: There is a very well known library called defered that does exactly this. You can find it on melpa or on github: https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-deferred. There is a good likelihood that you already have it installed if you are a package junkie

Answer (score 3):

You can start with something like:

```
(let ((proc1 (start-process "myproc1" t "cmd1")))
  (set-process-sentinel proc1
    (lambda (proc1 _string)
      (with-current-buffer (process-buffer proc1)
        (let ((proc2 (start-process "myproc2" t "cmd2")))
          (set-process-sentinel proc2
            (lambda (proc2 _string)
              (with-current-buffer (process-buffer proc2)
                (let ((proc3 (start-process "myproc3" t "cmd3")))
                  ...)))))))))
```